# Need examples of applications similar to TurboTax

Tags: usability, forms, interaction-design, desktop-application, webforms

I'm currently working through an application very similar to how TurboTax functions. I have a paper form that needs to be entered by users into my application (see example" https://www.cms.gov/Medicare/CMS-Forms/CMS-Forms/Downloads/CMS1500.pdf). In the current application, users jump around to fill out the different fields which is very confusing for them. They want the new application to match the paper form.

I'm looking for other applications that have a similar process to TurboTax - where a user has a paper form and has to fill it out online. Does anyone have examples I could use as inspiration?

Comment: Questions asking for 'Examples of X' aren't really suitable for Stack Exchange sites. There are generally lots of examples, and that doesn't necessarily mean any of them are 'correct'. It's just a poll really. You need to focus specifically on the UX requirement you have, and if a solution to your problem can be illustrated with an example of how an app / site solves that problem then it'll come out as part of the answer. Plus these type of questions get out of date quickly, and as a permanent repository for UX problems and solutions such questions are only relevant to one period of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your main challenge is to split the information you ask into chunks, in order to reduce the cognitive load. These chunks, like personal data, address, insurance details, can then be spaced out over multiple pages, essentially [creating a multi-step form](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/05/better-form-design-one-thing-per-page/). This way you create focus, making a complex form much less intimidating.

[image]

For example, an address form has multiple fields, but it’s a single, concrete question that is being asked of the user. It makes sense to tackle this question on one screen. Another benefit; if a user fills out a small form, errors are caught and presented early. If there’s one thing to fix, then it becomes easy to fix, which reduces the chance of users giving up.

Couple these multiple pages with a progress bar, and you turn an intimidatingly long task into something that tells your user that it is something they can easily complete.

Googling multi-step form should give you plenty of examples.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a step by step wizard that uses "progressive disclosure". Check out typeform.com for this style of getting users to enter information in drips (just like turbotax but not as dense) as opposed to one long form. Oscar health is another example how to get people to enter a lot of information. https://www.hioscar.com/ny click get a quote.